# ASP.NET TreeView javascript before postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, treeview, updatepanel

I'm trying to code what I think is a fairly routine AJAX pattern using TreeViews and UpdatePanels. My situation is this:

I have a TreeView within an UpdatePanel. I have a Literal within another UpdatePanel. When the user clicks on a node within the TreeView, the contents of the Literal are updated. Now, since the whole thing is asynchronous, there is of course a time lag between the click and the update of the Literal contents. During this time, I'd like to do two things:

1) Show an UpdateProgress, and

2) Clear the contents of the Literal

This is so that the user doesn't have to stare at the old contents while the new text is getting loaded asynchronously.

I can't seem to figure out an easy way to accomplish (2). I've been reading up on client side callbacks and using GetCallbackEventReference, but it seems like a very complicated approach to what is seemingly a simple problem.

Ideally, I would like to leave TreeView alone to do it's work. I don't want to get the contents myself and add them to the TreeView using JS. I'd just like to detect the node change event at the client side, clear up the Literal, and let TreeView go about with its normal operation.

Is this possible? Or are client call backs my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be wanting to play with the `PageRequestManager` from the ASP.NET AJAX library. Here's the MSDN reference for the PRM - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx.

Just be for warned Microsoft have stated that the TreeView can be problematic within the UpdatePanel and you'll also want to be **very careful of the performance**, particularly if you have a large TreeView (see my article on optimising the UpdatePanel performance - http://www.aaron-powell.com/blog.aspx?id=1195). You should really look at something like a jQuery plugin (eg: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/).

But to actually answer you're question you need to:

- Have a `BeginRequest` event handler which will then clear your literal and can even show a Loading (I'm not a fan of the UpdateProgress, I prefer much more granular control I get from doing it myself)
- Use the `EndRequest` event to ensure that the Loading component vanises

You could also make the TreeView a `AsyncPostbackTrigger` of the 2nd UpdatePanel on the page, or just call the Update method on it during the async postback of the TreeView

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and fixed it by creating a hidden html element that overlaps the area i want to hide.  I show it onSubmit and hide it in the window.onload during a postback.  It's not pretty, but it works and should be fast.